# When slideDown element, the rest of active elements slideUp

Tags: jquery

Mostly working, but I can't close the current one.
Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wsk3f/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul li a.show_child").click(function(){
        $("ul li a.show_child.active").removeClass("active");
        $("ul li a.show_child").next().slideUp(300);
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a boolean to check if the currently clicked elemnt already have the class "active", which means it should be closed only:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul li a.show_child").click(function() {

        var $this = $(this),
            closeOnly = $this.hasClass('active');

        $("ul li a.show_child.active").removeClass("active");
        $("ul li a.show_child").next().slideUp(300);

        if (!closeOnly) {
            $this.toggleClass("active");
            $this.next().slideToggle(300);
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Q8m9W/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul li a.show_child").click(function(){
        $("ul li a.show_child.active").removeClass("active");
        $("ul li a.show_child").next().slideUp(300);
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).next().stop().slideToggle(300);
    });
});
```